# Как передать данные в переменную за пределами foreach без индексов

Tags: php

Я хочу передать данные в переменную в таком формате как в фориче 
Вот так 
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в переменную передается вот так
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код который я использую

```
$data = [];
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $key => $value) {
        $data[] = $value;
    }
}
```

}

Что вовзращает $query->result_array()

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'ID' => 1, 
        'TABLENAME' => 'ITEMANUFACTURER',
        'ACTIONFIELD01' => '1',
        'ACTIONFIELD02' => NULL, 
        'ACTION' => 'I',
        'Code' => '1',
        'Description' => 'Manufacturer 1',
        'RtIPrice' => NULL, 
        'ColorCode' => NULL, 
        'ColorDescr' => NULL, 
        'Size' => NULL,
        'SizeThesi' => NULL,
    )
);
```

и далее так же только меняется индекс и ИД  array(
        1 => array(
            'ID' => 2

Мне нужно вернуть массив с картинки 1 как в фориче в переменную если это возможно

Comment: `$data[] = [$value[0]=>'???',$value[1]=>'???']` по скрину не понятно откуда у вас взялись значения.

Comment: Покажите содержимое массива `$query->result_array()` желательно через `var_export`

Comment: Откуда там взялся label и value? Какие поля вам нужны?

Comment: Мне не важны поля, это просто для примера, я хочу чтобы в переменную вернулось в формате как я указал выше без вложенных массивов

Comment: Значения из каких полей вам нужны? С `Description` или с `Size`? Или с какого ?

Comment: Мне нужны все поля просто в формате как они есть в фориче

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то это должно вам помочь

```
$data = [];
foreach($array as $a => $element){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($element as $key => $value){
        $data[$i]['label'] = $key;
        $data[$i]['value'] = $value;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => ID
            [value] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => TABLENAME
            [value] => ITEMANUFACTURER
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => ACTIONFIELD01
            [value] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => ACTIONFIELD02
            [value] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [label] => ACTION
            [value] => I
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [label] => Code
            [value] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [label] => Description
            [value] => Manufacturer 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [label] => RtIPrice
            [value] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [label] => ColorCode
            [value] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [label] => ColorDescr
            [value] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [label] => Size
            [value] => 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [label] => SizeThesi
            [value] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: Нет это не то, но спасибо за ваш ответ, мне нужно чтобы он вернулся в таком формате 
Array
        (
            [label] => ACTION
            [value] => I
        )

Comment: @ПашаИванов он так и возвращает `Array ( [label] => ACTION [value] => I`

Comment: он возвращает с индексом  
[11] => Array
        (
            [label] => SizeThesi
            [value] => 
        )

Comment: а как вы хотите? это массив! У него обязаны быть ключи и значения.

Comment: В этом то и суть вопроса - можно ли так сделать чтобы было как в форич в фориче он выводится без ключей, я это и спрашиваю и указал что я хочу в скринах

Comment: @ПашаИванов тогда можно было просто написать "Можно ли избавиться от ключей?" И ответ был бы простым - нет.

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Comment: @ПашаИванов Подскажите пожалуйста, а зачем это Вам нужно ?

Comment: Мне нужно было это чтобы сравнить элементы без ключей и индексов, это бы упростило мои задачи